# How to get % age of similar text of a column in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a column named `research_area` in a SQL Server table like this

```
digital library
approximation algorithm
real time application
approximation algorithm
applied mathematics
image processing
applied mathematics
evolutionary computation
image processing
image processing
image processing
image annotation
image segmentation
natural language processing
image processing
image segmentation
anomaly detection
image annotation
efficient algorithm
time series analysis
image annotation
image annotation
image processing
routing wireless networks
constrained project scheduling
image annotation
image segmentation
differential equation
image processing
collaborative filtering
image segmentation
image annotation
efficient algorithm
data reduction
image segmentation
image annotation
image processing
applied mathematics
image segmentation
image segmentation
```

Now I want to have some sort of processing that I'm able to get something like this i.e.

```
image processing    8
image annotation    7
image segmentation  7
applied mathematics 3
approximation algorithm 2
efficient algorithm 2
digital library 1
real time application   1
evolutionary computation    1
natural language processing 1
anomaly detection   1
time series analysis    1
routing wireless networks   1
constrained project scheduling  1
differential equation   1
collaborative filtering 1
data reduction  1
```

So now how can I get this by adding columns or whatever else?

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    aid, research_area as [Name], COUNT(research_area) as [Count] 
FROM
    sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY 
    research_area 
WHERE
    aid = 1653869
```

But it gives an error:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,
>   except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: use group by and count

Comment: @Shaharyar how can it be manipulated ?

Comment: You need to provide more details as to what the digit values are being derived from?

Comment: What do you mean by **manipulated**?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must `CAST` your column to `varchar` or `nvarchar` to use GROUP BY clause on it:

```
SELECT aid, CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [research_area], COUNT(research_area) [Count] 
FROM sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY  CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)), aid
WHERE aid = 1653869
```

[SQL Server Error Messages - Msg 306](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-306.aspx)

Comment: @Shaharyar--I have to get output for a single id for example I have tried query like this i.e.  **SELECT aid, research_area as [Name], COUNT(research_area) as [Count] from sub_aminer_paper
GROUP BY research_area where aid = 1653869** but where clause error

Comment: @maliks Change your query to `SELECT research_area as [Name], COUNT(research_area) as [Count] from sub_aminer_paper where aid = 1653869 GROUP BY research_area ` . This will work, but will not give you `aid` in output

Comment: @DhruvJoshi--as type of field i.e. **research_area** is text so it can't be used in Count operator, this raises error

Comment: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: count(research_area) creating the problem

Comment: You'll have to change the type of your column for this query, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, clarifying your question here.  You want to get the weight of each "IDENTICAL" value in a given column, compared to the total number of rows within the named column?

As in, you want to know if there are 100 columns, and 8 are of an identical name the digit 8 should represent that 8% of the given rows are named "whatever" and so on?

Comment: --Yeah I want to have weight of each "IDENTICAL" column value as output

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,

```
select * from (SELECT   
research_area,aid,count(*) AS SumOfValues,
(100.0 * (count(*)) / (SUM(count(*)) OVER())) AS percnt
FROM    table
GROUP BY research_area,aid) b where aid=1653869;
```

EDIT:
Gives you count and percent of each value.

Comment: @learningNew--where to put aid as I have to select the output for some specific aid i.e. aid = 1653869

Comment: and also research_area is of type "text" can't be counted

Comment: @maliks Edited the query,use  * inside count if datatype is text.

Comment: still same issue, I think omit percentage for some time then what will be the query

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the answer given by @Shaharyar, so this is the answer that worked fine

```
SELECT aid, CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)) [research_area], COUNT(research_area) [Count] 
FROM sub_aminer_paper 
GROUP BY  CAST(research_area as VARCHAR(100)), aid
WHERE aid = 1653869
```

and this is the output what required.
Thanks **Shaharyar**
 [image]